# Reference a file stored in internal memory inside HTML of a webview

Tags: android, image, webview, storage, internal

I have a webview :

```
this.webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/test.html");
```

in test.html i would like to write this :

```
<img src="file:///data/data/com.myapp/myimage.jpg" />
```

I doesn't work for me so i found another topic saying i could use a contentProvider but i guess the purpose is different as i don't want to display only one image but i need references to images stored inside the interna memory to build a full designed HTML page ... is thre something i missed ? ( gotta try to root the device to check that the pictures are well written inside it).

Many thanks :)

Comment: _It doesnt work for me_ is not gonna tell us what the actual problem is. please elaborate your problem. BTW, I suppose you know that the files stored in internal memory are accesible only for the applications creating them.

Comment: Hi ! The web content is inside the webview which belongs to the app so i may access the internal memory no ? (topic modified to explain a little more)

Comment: After rooted device + install of busybox (to get busybox cp command), seems that the picture is 1ko :(